# Reload page after DB update with ajax

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, model-view-controller

So I need to reload my page after sending data to the controller with an ajax request. The controller saves it into the DB and then the reloaded page should have the updated content:

**[Controller]**

```
public class ProcessingController : Controller
{
    ManageProcessing runManager = new ManageProcessing();

    [Authorize] 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        RunModel rm = new RunModel
        {
            RunList = runManager.GetRunModelList()
        };
        return View(rm);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveReprocessData(Run runPost)
    {
        runManager.SaveToDataBase(runPost);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Processing");
    }
}
```

**[View]**

```
 function Reprocess() {
        var checkedID = '#' + document.querySelector('input[name="select"]:checked').value;
        var line = $(checkedID)[0].children;
        var obj = {};

        obj.ID = line[0].textContent;
        obj.EndDate = line[1].textContent;
        obj.ProcessedDate = line[2].textContent;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveReprocessData", "Processing")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {    
                window.location.reload();
                alert("updated licenses");
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert(ex);
                console.log("we have failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

What should SaveReprocessData return to receive the new view on the View? And how to use that return?

Comment: Why do you have to reload the page? Just make the endpoint your sending your data to, return the saved data. Once you receive that data update the website's content using scripts. Reloading disrupts the user experience and is most likely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with tobias. Your defeating the whole purpose of using ajax by trying to reload the page but your solution would be to just change the return type of your **SaveReprocessData** method and return a new list of data

```
[HttpPost]
public RunModel SaveReprocessData(Run runPost)
{
    runManager.SaveToDataBase(runPost);

    return runManager.GetRunModelList();
}
```

Also unless there are values generated on the server-side that your client side requires after you execute an ajax POST request you can avoid an additional call to the database all together. You will just need to update your javascript code to something like this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveReprocessData", "Processing")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {    
               // window.location.reload();
               // alert("updated licenses");
                 reloadView(obj); 
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert(ex);
                console.log("we have failed");
            }
        });
```